# Project configuration for IDEs use same code formatting

Tags: java, code-formatting

## Issue

It is common in many projects that each developer uses the IDE of their preference, where the most common are Eclipse, Netbeans and Intellij.

In this case, they use that shortcut for formatting the entire file, and code formatting conflicts often occur, which makes revision implementation very difficult.

I've heard of **plugin** ([EditorConfig](http://editorconfig.org/)) and **XML config files** to solve this issue and keep a unique formatting for the project, but have not yet seen this being used effectively.

## Question

Is there a common practice for solving this problem, which is valid for these major IDEs? If possible, add an example configuration to the answer.

Comment: In my experience, the most effective approach here is to add a code formatting step (or hook) in the version control. Then individual developers can choose the IDE (and formatting) they prefer locally.

Comment: In my experience,  you'd enforce the Maven checkstyle plugin, for example, or some form of linter. If you really want to tie to an IDE, force everyone to use one IDE so you may share style guides using whatever plugin supports that feature

Answer (score 1):

In terms of Java, there's [Checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/index.html)

> Checkstyle is a development tool to help programmers write Java code that adheres to a coding standard. It automates the process of checking Java code to spare humans of this boring (but important) task. This makes it ideal for projects that want to enforce a coding standard.

And plugins exist for both Maven and Gradle (which I'd recommend using for any Java project)

You may also integrate tooling into your source control that performs these tasks, but it would be preferred that developers check formatting before pushing